# How to share content dynamically from web site using javascript to facebook user wall?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my requirement,

I have a website, which integrates with facebook.
Here I am fetching latest post (**description** and **image**) from company facebook page. I have added like, comment and share buttons.
I am using Grapth API calls to fetch the latest posts. Everything(calls) using javascript.

My Question, When a user clicks on Share button, share UI popup comes up with text field and image. But I want to share the description which has been retrieved earlier.

Is there any way to share description and image?

Thanks In Advance.
Khader.

Comment: This is all documented in the Facebook Open Graph API documentation.  Can you show us your code and explain what's going wrong with it?

Comment: I am fetching post using ajax call as below,

Comment: I am fetching post using ajax call as below,
function 
facebookPosts(){
$.ajax({url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/423182757726897/feed?fields=message,picture,created_time&date_format=U&key=value&access_token='accesstoken',type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
                       $("#facebook-message-first").val(element[0].message)  ;
                        var facebookFirstImageSrc = element[0].picture;
                         if(facebookFirstImageSrc){
 $("#facebook-first-image").attr(src,facebookFirstImageSrc);

Comment: Displaying post details (description and image) application UI has "share button". on click of share button I want to display the description and image in share pop-up. The share pop-up loading image but not the description. Code sample is as below, 
$( "#first-like-share" ).click(function() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
FB.ui({
method: 'share',
href :'https://www.facebook.com/LPLFinancialLLC/posts/'+postId+'?&description='+firstComment,
}, function(response){
});